# Can't Find Where To Install Extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

First of all, I am new to Typo3. 
I installed Typo3 via composer ( version 9.5.1 ).
According to their [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtensionManagement/Index.html), in order to install an extension,I need to open ADMIN TOOLS > Extensions from the admin panel.
I can't find ADMIN TOOLS on my admin panel ( attached is a screenshot of my admin panel ). Please, can someone help me out? is there a configuration that is needed before ADMIN TOOLS appear in the admin panel?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do not have the system maintainer permissions. Log in to `typo3/install.php` and create a new administrator with system maintainer permissions.

There you should also be able to install / activate extensions.

Otherwise add the uid of your backend user to the list of systemMaintainers inside `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`: `['SYS']['systemMaintainers'] = [1],`

Comment: The admin is in the list of maintainers, or do I need to create another user?

Comment: thanks @Daniel. I discovered that Typo3 created 2 users with the name "admin". I just added the other user in the list and the link is now available

Comment: If he is, he should see the module. As he doesn't see the module, he might not be in the list.

You can check the list inside `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` it's an array of be_user UIDs. `$GLOBALS['SYS']['systemMaintainers']`